# Send pre-fx signal of a track to the return track in Ableton

Tags: ableton-live

Is there a way in Ableton to send the unaltered signal of a particular track to a return track? By unaltered I mean the signal before the insert effects kick in. I have a vocal which I would like to filter in and out, but would still like to hear the unfiltered delay on my return track, even when the vocal is completely inaudible due to the low pass filter insert.

I tried fiddling around with "pre" and "post" in my Master channel for the return track of interest, but this still kicks in post-effect and only works when my volume fader is all the way down.

Answer (score 3):

Create an extra helper audio track, and configure it like this:

- Set the **Audio From** i.e. input to be your **original track** that has the effects.
- Set the **Audio From** as **Pre FX**.
- Set **Audio To** to **Sends Only**, so that it doesn't contribute to the main mix.
- In **Sends**, dial in the amount of effect send you want.
- Switch **Monitor** to **In** so that it constantly just channels audio from its input to its output.

Like so:

[image: Extra helper track in Ableton]